How to prevent an AI model from generating its own answers outside of a predefined corpus?
so I'm developing a chatbot using Python. I integrated a vector database called Word2Vec, and I'm using the Zephyr model from Hugging Face. I have created a very simple text file corpus, and I want my model to go through this corpus when responding. This is actually working as intended. However, the issue arises when there are no details regarding the user input in the corpus.
For example, let's say there is a start date in my corpus. When I ask the model about the start date, it gives this information. But if there is no information in my corpus about a legal team, and I ask the model, it generates an answer that says, 'Yes, there is a legal department.'
What's your suggestion to stop this and restrict my model only to the corpus?
Appreciate any suggestions and thanks in advance."
I've tried giving is specific keywords. but this is not practical and scalable.

from langchain import HuggingFaceHub, PromptTemplate, LLMChain
import gensim.downloader as api

word_vectors = api.load("word2vec-google-news-300")

template = """
{corpus_text}
give an answer to the {query}:
{query}
"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=['corpus_text', 'query'])

model_id = "HuggingFaceH4/zephyr-7b-beta"

conv_model = HuggingFaceHub(
    huggingfacehub_api_token="12345",  
    repo_id=model_id,
    model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.1, "max_new_tokens": 1000}
)

conv_chain = LLMChain(llm=conv_model,
                      prompt=prompt,
                      verbose=True)

corpus_file = r/myfile.txt

with open(corpus_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    corpus_text = file.read()

while True:
    user_input = input("You: ")
    
    
    generated_prompt = prompt.template.format(corpus_text=corpus_text, query=user_input)
    
    
    result = conv_chain.run({"query": user_input, "corpus_text": corpus_text})
    
    print("Model:", result)


Have you used temperature variable ?
Also coding suggestion is asked by providing code and not theory

Have you heard about prompt engineering? Search and read papers about it

Sorry About Not prividing code.this is my first question here.i added the code to the question.

Your code shows a bunch of word-vectors loaded – the 4GB circa-2012 GoogleNews vectors – but then the object word_vectors is never used for anything, so won't have any effect on your responses. If you meant to use it to help select some portion of your corpus, in a 'retrieval-augmented-generation' (RAG) style – that's not happening. And further: simple single-word vectors are a pretty crude & weak basis for modeling of longer texts.
Your prompt template also looks a bit confused. You include the entire corpus – which might be many thousands or tens-of-thousands or hundreds-of-thousands of words? – at the top, then repeat the query twice.
For example, if your corpus is the sentence "Math is hard, let's go shopping." and the query is "What is 2 + 2?", what your template actually passes to the LLM is:
"""
Math is hard, let's go shopping.
give an answer to the What is 2 + 2?:
What is 2 + 2?
"""

All that said:
LLMs are inherently prone to confabulating plausible texts ('hallucination') that don't precisely conform to their training material or the written instructions and material in their context window. This may be a larger problem with smaller models and higher temperatures.
There are no guarantees, but some tactics that may help:

Ensuring the most relevant information isn't "too far" before the generation.

IIUC – & this may be more a vague approximation than the literal truth – a Mistral-7b tune like your Zephyr-7b-beta has a 'context-window' of about 4k tokens, where each token is something between a word & meaningful subword. (So: this could be less than 4k words.)
That means generation can only definitively work off of the last ~4k words in your prompt (plus the LLM's inbuilt tendencies), plus some much vaguer retained sense of earlier context (that fades quickly with distance).
So any time your query needs info more than 4k words back in your corpus, the LLM will be more guessing/hallucinating than deducing from the corpus.
The gist of RAG is to ensure the best reference info is fed the LLM just before it needs it, so it's in the context-window. So if you upgraded your code to put the most relevant (by some semantic-similarity measure) excerpts of your corpus into the prompt, just before the generation, you'd likely get better results.

Using larger model, a model with a longer effective context, or adjusting the generation temperature. You'd have to tinker to find what works well for your specific domain, resource limits, and typical queries and desired responses.

Stacking techniques, such as using a 2nd LLM pass (itself perhaps enhanced with some corpus-excerpt-retrieval) to check that an answer does not contradict your canonical reference snippets, or choose which of sevral alternate generations is best.


Ultimately, if you want your system to only say things that are definitively in the corpus, than LLMs may be both overkill, and unhelpfully prone to hallucinations, for your needs.
You might just want to break your corpus into chunks/ranges, then use some pre-LLM info-retrieval – keyword search, semantic similarity search, etc – to echo back only the best exact-unaltered text chunks that are canonical.
(Such a system can sometimes be refined with LLM techniques, even if the LLM isn't directly composing the answers. For example, a technique called 'HyDE' uses an LLM to generate candidate answers for a query that you don't ever show the user, or care if they're wrong - they're just used to find similar texts in your verified answers.)
